# Hotfix KB2731284 - How to install?

Tags: windows, mongodb, hotfix

OK, I feel like an absolute idiot here...

I'm trying to setup MongoDB on a Windows 7 x64 machine in en-gb. I am following the instructions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) and have downloaded the hotfix, extracted and now what?

Inside the folder there are several files, all identical in name except for the language - BR, ES, FR, IT, JP, MX, NL, PL, TR

When downloading the package on the Microsoft website it said that the language option for my system was available (English (United Kingdom)) but, and maybe I'm going mad here, none of those prefixes are English, right?

I know that someone is going to point out something ridiculously obvious but I am just stuck right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download it from microsoft site, 
http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix405791/7600/free/451413_intl_x64_zip.exe
it will open only one file: Windows6.1-KB2731284-v3-x64.msu which is easy to install.
Good luck.

Comment: Network Error (tcp_error) 

A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.

Can You describe why I got that message?